# How to use Derby database with Using Join And aggregate functions together?

Tags: function, join, aggregate, derby

I have  two table in my data base As below:

```
CUSTOMER (
  ID integer Generated Always As Identity,
  FIRSTNAME varchar(32) not null,
  LASTNAME varchar(32) not null,
  PHONENUMBER varchar(11) not null,
  ADDRESS varchar(225),
primary key (id)
);
```

and

```
APP.ORDERS (
  ID integer not null default AUTOINCREMENT: start 1 increment 1,
  CUSTOMER_ID integer References Customer(ID) ,
  EMPLOYEEID integer References Employee(ID),
  DATEOFDELIVERY date,
  primary key (id),
);
```

When I try To join This two table as below every thing is fine:

```
 SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,firstname,LASTNAME,Address,phoneNumber From APP.Customer 
 INNER JOIN APP.Orders ON customer.ID = customer_ID 
 WHERE ORDERS.dateOfDelivery Between '2012-09-01' AND '2012-11-11'
```

but When I use Aggregate Function as below it give me Error:

```
SELECT Count(CUSTOMER_ID),firstname,LASTNAME,Address,phoneNumber 
From APP.Customer                         
INNER JOIN APP.Orders ON customer.ID = customer_ID 
WHERE ORDERS.dateOfDelivery Between '2012-09-01' AND '2012-11-11' ;
```

Error:

```
[2012-07-20 08:07:04] [42Y35][30000] Column reference 'FIRSTNAME' is invalid. When the SELECT list contains at least one aggregate then all entries must be valid aggregate expressions.
```

I try to change the last code above to Orders.Count(CUSTOMR_ID) to tell the database the correct table but it give me error that there is no schema with name Orders so I change it to APP.Orders.Count(CUSTOMER_ID) but it never solve the problem.
 Error :`Schema 'ORDERS' does not exist`

UPDATING QUESTION:

I Figur out that very simple Query Like :

```
SELECT COUNT(*),ID FROM Orders
```

will caused to This Error :

```
[2012-07-20 09:01:50] [42Y35][30000] Column reference 'ID' is invalid. When the SELECT list contains at least one aggregate then all entries must be valid aggregate expressions.
```

So It means that it is not possible to have both aggregate function and simple column names together but I am wonder how to supply the expected out put with any equivalent Query?**Any Idea?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GROUP BY is the correct approach. You need to group by all the non-aggregate columns, as in:

```
SELECT Count(CUSTOMER_ID),firstname,LASTNAME,Address,phoneNumber 
From APP.Customer                         
INNER JOIN APP.Orders ON customer.ID = customer_ID 
WHERE ORDERS.dateOfDelivery Between '2012-09-01' AND '2012-11-11' 
group by firstname,lastname,address,phonenumber;
```

Think about it this way: you want to gather together all the orders for a particular customer (that's what GROUP BY does), then you want to count up all those orders (that's what the COUNT() function does).

Comment: Thnaks a lot man, today I'm deploying my application and when I start testing with derby db (instead of MySQL) it give the same error and your solution fixe it. you saved the day

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,Count(CUSTOMER_ID),firstname,LASTNAME,Address,phoneNumber 
From APP.Customer                         
INNER JOIN APP.Orders ON customer.ID = customer_ID 
WHERE ORDERS.dateOfDelivery Between '2012-09-01' AND '2012-11-11' 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID,firstname,LASTNAME,Address,phoneNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent query in derby database is as below :

```
SELECT customer.firstName As FirstName ,
       customer.lastName AS LastName,
       customer.phoneNumber AS Telephone,
       customer.address AS Address, 
       (SELECT COUNT(OrderID) FROM Orders)  
  FROM Customer join Orders On orders.customer_ID = customer.id WHERE orders.dateOfDelivery Between '2012-09-01' And '2012-11-11'
```

The fact is that this database can not realize queries that contains both aggregation function  and column name together like other data bases. The equivalent query that I mentioned will give the same out put but according to http://old.nabble.com/Nested-query-in-conjunction-with-ordering---unreasonably-slow-td15259785.html its performance is not good.The Query that mentioned by Bryan Pendleton also is true equivalent for this query.